# How to design & Implement containerize architecture for nginx with reactjs and laravel with mongo?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, architecture

I'm using reactjs for frontend with Nginx load balancer and laravel for backend with MongoDB.
as old architecture design, code upload to GitHub with different frontend and backend repo.

still did not use DOCKER AND KUBERNETS, I want to implement them, in the new Architecture design, **I used a private cloud server** so, restricted to deploying on AWS\AZURE\GCP\etc...

*share your Architecture plan and implementation for a better approach to microservices!*

Answer (score 1):

as per my thinking,

1. first make a docker file for react and laravel project
2. then upload to docker private registry.[dockerhub]
3. install docker and k8s on VM
4. deploy container of 1=react and 2=laravel from image
5. also deploy 3=nginx and 4=mongo container from default market image

**Some of my questions:**

1. How to make the connection?
2. How to take a new pull on the container, for the new update release version?
3. How to make a replica, for a disaster recovery plan?
4. How to monitor errors and performance?
5. How to make the pipeline MOST important?
6. How to make dev, staging, and production environments?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of planning question, more of the task can be automated by developer/devops, except few administrative task like monitoring and environment creation.

still  this can be shared responsibility. or if team is available to manage product/services.

Comment: Yes you are right, kindly define it

Answer (score 0):

You can use gitlab, which can directly attach to kub8 provider. Can reduce multiple build steps.

Comment: hi @mi3afzal, can you explain the process and step so i can implement it